# Create a transcation on Ethereum (Smart Contract)

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am new in Ethereum. I am trying to create a DAPP using Smart Contract, I have created a function to create a transaction on Ethereum. How I did was I created a defaultGas with the coinBase to pass in as parameters. When I hit the button the on the UI, and it doesn't not prompt me the MetaMask, and the transaction was created successfully. I am just wondering this is the right way to create a transaction without prompting users the MetaMask to manipulate the Gas?

Please advice.
Cheers

Comment: Maybe try posting some code?

Comment: I would say that it's quite a good option to not to rely on MetaMask or any other clients you dont have control of. If you are creating a DAPP, you can create a server for it which will interact with hosted Geth/Parity node using web3. In this case you will have much more control

Comment: @AndreyDegtyaruk - Thank you so much for your advice. :). You were right; this is how did. I have a server which just wired-up the local node (Geth and Azure). From the business perspective, this is the best way to control the business model(Gas price).

Comment: More advice would be most welcome.

Comment: @AndreyDegtyaruk - I have another question, while I was testing the Smart Contract - solidity code, I had noticed that there is another input parameter which is the "Gas Price".  The user would manipulate the "Gas Price" on the MetaMask or others tool for the transaction speed and performance purpose. Well, in this case, what will be the ideal default "Gas Price" is appropriate for the transaction?  I supposed the default/lowest  "Gas Price" is 5(WEI). 

Thank You.

Comment: @DavidB I would recommend to use lowest price. Gas price is depends on the ethereum network load. When something llike CryptoKitties happens the gas price increases. 
If you are using web3js there are some helpfull methods: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgasprice
It takes the the gas price is determined by the x latest blocks median gas price.

Comment: @AndreyDegtyaruk - Thank you so much for your kind advice. I will take a look at it. :)

Comment: @DavidB I would like to suggest you to take a look at our dApp(ICO contributor dashboard). I think it can be quite helpful to look at some realworld examples: https://github.com/JincorTech/backend-ico-dashboard/

Comment: @AndreyDegtyaruk- Thank you so much :)

Comment: @AdamKipnis - What you think about this? Am I heading in the right direction for not showing the MetaMask?